# How to implement if file in request.files is not empty

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

The Logic I'm attempting to implement: if the user doesn't upload a file to a Filefield thus leaving it empty, then don't upload the file to the S3 bucket or create a link to it. Line 8/9 doesn't do what I expected cause it still uploads empty files to the bucket & creates a link to it on my ticket.

```
uploads = [['frontview', 'upload', '<b>Frontview: </b>'],['backview', 'upload2', '<b>Backview: </b>'], ['electricalsupply', 'upload3', '<b>Electrical Supply: </b>'], ['fullstructure', 'upload4', '<b>Full Structure: </b>'], ['controlroom', 'upload5', '<b>Control Room: </b>'], ['otherdoc', 'upload6', '<b>Other Documentation: </b>'], ['customersignoff', 'upload7', '<b>Customer Sign-Off: </b>']]
        file_upload_urls = []
        folder = str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(' ', '') + '/' # sets folder to the current date & time while getting rid of spaces & adding forward slash for linking purposes
        for upload in uploads: #loops through uploads array
            files = request.files.getlist(upload[1])
            section_urls = []
            for file in files: #loops through uploads array more specifically each File (upload, upload2, upload3, etc)
                if file not in request.files:
                    filename = str(upload[0] + '_' + file.filename).replace(' ', '')
                    section_urls.append(current_app.config['NEVCODOCS_BASE_URL'] + folder + filename)
                    path = "ServiceRegistration/" + folder + filename
                    s3.Bucket('nevcodocs').put_object(Key=path, Body=file)
            file_upload_urls.append([upload[2], section_urls])
​
        # Installation photos are placed in an unordered list & formats links of photos for ticket submission
        for section in file_upload_urls:
            ticket_html = ticket_html + section[0] + '<ul>'
            for url in section[1]:
                ticket_html = ticket_html + '<li> <href=' + url + '">' + url + '</href></li>'
            ticket_html = ticket_html + '</ul>'
```

The code below is a snippet from above, but I figured I would add the entire function for context. My intended function would be: While looping through each FileField, retrieve the data of each FileField, and run a check to see if a file was uploaded in each field. If there's data, then upload that file to S3 Bucket. If the FileField is empty, loop moves on to the next FileField. I've tried `if len(request.files[file]) != 0`, `if not request.files.get(file, None)`, and `if not request.files[file].filename == ''` to no avail as those either lead to a 400 Bad Request, omits every FileField even if a file was uploaded, or continues to upload blank files.

```
        for file in files: #loops through uploads array more specifically each FileField (upload, upload2, upload3, etc)
            # if not len(request.files[file]) == 0:
            if file not in files:
                filename = str(upload[0] + '_' + file.filename).replace(' ', '')
                section_urls.append(current_app.config['NEVCODOCS_BASE_URL'] + folder + filename)
                path = "ServiceRegistration/" + folder + filename
                s3.Bucket('nevcodocs').put_object(Key=path, Body=file)
```

Comment: Please paste all relevant code in the question. We cannot copy from screenshots.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thought it would look cleaner in a pastebin. I have updated the post with the code snippet

Comment: Now, please kindly format it appropriately, so that it could be actually executed in Python.

Comment: @StevenNguyen "Looking cleaner" is less important to Stack Overflow than being available forever. If dpaste goes under or purges their old data or etc then this question stops being a useful reference for future viewers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I believe I've done as requested. Let me know if there's anything else.

Comment: if you loop over `for file in files:`, `if file not in files:` will always be `False`, because you just got the file out of the same list.

Comment: So that's why none of my files are being sent to the S3 bucket despite having a file uploaded to the fields. I've tried `if request.files[file] not in files`, but that sent a 400 Bad Request. `if file in files:` uploaded everything even if the field was empty so that's not it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: if not file.filename == '':